# Precision level of numeric luminosity sensor on GPIO Raspberry Pi

Tags: node.js, raspberry-pi2, gpio

I just got shipped a Luminosity sensor today.
I want to write in nodejs a function that get live data from it(using the "onoff" package).
I manage to do it, here is the code,

```js
"use strict";

var Gpio = require('onoff').Gpio,
    pr = new Gpio(4, 'in'),
    readInterval = setInterval(getPrValue, 25);

function getPrValue(){
    console.log("Value of photo resistance : "+pr.readSync());
}
    
process.on('SIGINT', function(){
    clearInterval(readInterval);
    pr.unexport();
});
```

(For info I plugged the "VCC" pin directly in 3.3V GPIO pin, i plugged the GND in one of the GND GPIO pin, and the other pin to plug is called "DO" and I plugged it on the GPIO pin 4 !

But the problem is that I get only 0 and 1 from it. I thought I would get a value between 0.00000 and 1 you know ?

So my question is ; is there any way to get a precise value of the ambient luminosity or the little things I got just send 1 and 0 ?

Hope someone can help me. Have a nice day

Comment: Study the sensor's datasheet on how to interface it.  It's probably a single-wire data channel (e.g. I2C or 1-Wire).

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to get a better data than 0 or 1. Since the DO only send to state